# Keeping count of the overflowing elements in a container

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the following markup (jsfiddle provided below)

```
 <div class="masterContainer"> 
        <div class="filterContainerStrip"> 
            <div class="filterButton">Filter 001</div>
            <div class="filterButton">Filter 002</div>
             ...
        </div>
        <div class="hiddenFilterCount"> ... 4 filters hidden </div>
 </div>
```

Where there may be any variable number of `filterButton`s in `filterContainerStrip` but the overflowing `filterButtons` are dropped down and no longer visible by setting `max-width`, `height`, and `overflow-y: hidden` on the container.

I would like to know how many of the `filterButtons` are currently hidden so I can display it to the user.

Here is the fiddle  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FbXep/2/)

**Updated fiddle**

Thanks

Comment: did you try using a counter when you are hiding the options? just a simple `count++` would work

Comment: So there's no special selector on the hidden elements, and they are not really hidden, they are just outside a parent that has no visible overflow, right ?

Comment: Iterate over each element, check if the `offset().top >=` the `parent().height()`, ifit is, `i++`, then after the `$.each iteration`, do `ele.text('there are +' i '+ hidden elements');`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Here is your suggestion http://jsfiddle.net/FbXep/6/ . It gives incorrect count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If top position (relative to parent) + height is higher than the parents' height, or left position + width is higher than the parents' width assume the element is not visible:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var hidden = $('.filterButton').filter(function(){  
      return (this.offsetTop + this.offsetHeight > this.parentNode.clientHeight)
          || (this.offsetLeft + this.offsetWidth > this.parentNode.clientWidth);
    });    

   $('.hiddenFilterCount').text('... ' + hidden.length + ' filters hidden');    
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nvgU5/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is having strange behavior here http://jsfiddle.net/FbXep/8/  . It seems to display the incorrect count and does not account for if I resize my browser to fit more than one screen. I don't know if you have more than one or are unable to test that.

Comment: yeah, fixed now :) You have to count in the filter W/H

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var $cont= $('.filterContainerStrip'), contH=$cont.height();

var hiddenEls= $cont.children().filter(function(){
    return $(this).position().top >= contH;
}).length;

$('.hiddenFilterCount').text( hiddenEls+' filters hidden');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FbXep/3/

Comment: Thanks for giving it a go but that doesn't work correctly. Displays incorrect count and then always displays 0 hidden if > 6 visible. Here's an updated fiddle with the correct filter labels, to the right-most visible # plus the hidden # should equal 12 (or more if I add filters). Also it has to work dynamically on window resize or zoom.

Comment: where's updated fiddle? Easy to wrap this code in a `resize` handler also